# Правильное окончание

Tags: согласование

Добрый день! Как правильно писать: принять участие в заседании кафедры, посыщенн**ом** или посвященн**ому**? Спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

Окончания прилагательных и причастий проверяются вопросом от определяемого слова. В заседании какОМ? ПосвященнОМ.